# How can I use PWM to power a 1.5v dc motor with an 5v board Arduino UNO?

Tags: arduino, pwm, dc-motor, arduino-uno

I tried to calculate the value for analogwrite which is 77 but that doesn't work. I also tried a bunch of other value but none of them spin the motor. Is this possible and am I missing something? the motor is a FF-N20ta-2232 and i am using pin 13 on the Arduino uno.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flFdPk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: How much current does your motor need? The Uno can only supply about 10-40mA. Your motor might need more current.

Comment: Don't try driving an electric motor, even a small one, from a microcontroller output. Your motor is rated to draw 0.2A at its nominal voltage. You will likely damage the Uno. You can buy a cheap H bridge shield to drive the motor instead.

Comment: Also, the "analog" output of the microcontroller is a series of pulses. The motor has high inductance which means that there will be a high voltage spike every time you switch off the output. These spikes have the ability to destroy the output of the microcontroller - if not the whole chip.

Comment: You need an H bridge to drive the motor, but beware not to buy one of the horrible ones based on a Darlington chip like an L293 or L298 - find something with an FET chip or discrete FETs.   If you only want to run it in a single direction you can use a single NFET on the negative side, there are a number of existing questions on that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the Arduino microcontroller is not suited to driving any motor directly. See the comments for a discussion of suitable solutions, including H-bridge drivers. Motor shields are widely available for Arduino Uno controllers.

Secondly, I have checked the [Arduino reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/) for AnalogWrite and it appears this function is not available for pin 13 on the Arduino Uno which you mentioned you are trying to use.

> On most Arduino boards (those with the ATmega168 or ATmega328P), this
>   function works on pins 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, and 11. On the Arduino Mega, it
>   works on pins 2 - 13 and 44 - 46. Older Arduino boards with an ATmega8
>   only support analogWrite() on pins 9, 10, and 11.

Finally, if you would like to use this motor then you should check the [datasheet](http://www.acp-mt.com/a/product/Buspro/youshua/diya/Nxi/2017/0213/176.html). The motor is rated for a nominal voltage of 1.2 V and a no load current of 0.2 A (200 mA). Under load or stalled, the motor will draw more current.

Comment: Beware that most cheap "motor shields" have the problematic Darlington drivers like L293, L298, etc which should be avoided